# Linq To SQL Contains

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

How can I go about converting this SQL statement to LINQ:

```
SELECT     [Content].[Content], [Content].ListOrder, [Content].ContentTypeId,        
           [Content].ContentId
FROM       [Content] INNER JOIN
           GroupContentPermission ON [Content].ContentId = GroupContentPermission.ContentId 
WHERE      GroupContentPermission.GroupId IN 
           (SELECT GroupId FROM GroupUser WHERE GroupUser.UserId = 169)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation to LINQ is generally pretty straightforward except for one special trick in the case of your query.  You can translate your select, where, and from statements in a natural way as shown below.  In the case of an `IN` statement though, you have to get the results from the inner subquery *first*, and then check if the inner subquery `.Contains` the value you want to check.

```
var groups =
   (from gu in GroupUser
    where gu.UserId == 169
    select gu.GroupId).ToList();

var result = 
    from p in GroupContentPermission
    join c in Content on p.ContentId equals c.ContentId
    where groups.Contains(p.GroupId)
    select new { c.Content, c.ListOrder, c.ContentTypeID, c.ContentId };

// result should contain the same results as the SQL query
```

Here are some other resources you may find helpful as well (you can find many more resources and tutorials on LINQ if you do a quick google search.  There are literally *thousands*):

- [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/), a SQL to LINQ converter.
- [LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.com/), a simple .NET/LINQ tester for rapid experimentation
- ScottGu's definitive guide to [Using LINQ To SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)
- Related SO question: [What are some good LINQ resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740/what-are-some-good-linq-resources), which references a tutorial called [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx).

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your help. The resources are helpful as well!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already link the tables with foreign keys in your model (DBML/EntityFrameworks):

```
Contents.Where(x => x.GroupContentPermission.GroupUser.UserId == 169).Select(x => new {
    x.Content,
    x.ListOrder,
    x.ContentTypeId,
    x.ContentId })
```

or preferrably just grab the full Content object, and use any column you want:

```
var contents = Contents.Where(x => x.GroupContentPermission.GroupUser.UserId == 169).ToList();

foreach (var content in contents)
    Console.Write(content.Content);
```